# How to get values from spinner using recyclerView adapter

Tags: android

I am working on a attendance application for school. I have recylerView adapter for populating students list. I have created a spinner for each student for getting attendance status. What i want is selected status for each item from spinner.

Comment: Have you tried anything? also paste some related code.

Answer (score 0):

To improve performance,

Remove allocations from onBindViewHolder
Reuse LayoutInflater, instead of getting a new one every time.
Minimize repetitive work in onBindViewHolder implementation
Spinner Adapter should also recycle the views
Background

When using an adapter for scrolling, the most important thing to make sure is that we DON'T allocate new objects (or minimize it as possible).

The whole purpose of a RecyclerView with an Adapter is to make sure we Recycle our objects so that the work needed during scroll is minimal.

Since allocating memory is very "expensive", to improve scrolling performance, the first thing to look for is allocations during the onBindViewHolder. All allocations if any should be made in the onCreateViewHolder.

Once all allocations are cleared, if we still have lagging, it is time for some micro improvements. These includes improving code quality, reuse logic results, etc.

What to do?

1) Remove allocations from onBindViewHolder

In the following code:

```
MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
inflater.inflate(R.menu.delete_menu, popup.getMenu());

viewHolder.deleteMenu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        popup.show();
    }
});

popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_delete) {
            removeData(holder.getAdapterPosition());
            ((CartActivity) activity).checkIfEmpty();
        }

        return true;
    }
});
```

You currently have 3 direct allocations (new) and some indirect allocations (inflate). Change this code so that all allocations are in the onCreateViewHolder. For example:

In onCreateViewHolder do the allocations like so:

// Allocate Listener only ONCE per recycled view

````
viewHolder.deleteMenu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // Get needed data from the view TAG, we will set it later
        final int itemPosition = (Integer)view.getTag();

        // Do work only when needed - when user clicked the button
        final PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(getContext(), viewHolder.deleteMenu);
        MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.delete_menu, popup.getMenu());

        popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                // Do logic using itemPosition etc
                return true;
            }
        });

        popup.show();
    }
}); 
In onBindViewHolder bind relevant data like so:

viewHolder.deleteMenu.setTag(holder.getAdapterPosition());
2) Reuse LayoutInflater, instead of getting a new one every time.

In the following code:

``` public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View rowView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(viewType == TYPE_PRODOTTO ? R.layout.item_cart : R.layout.item_cart_sconto, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(rowView);
}
````

You are getting a new LayoutInflater every time. It is a waste. Better to get one in the Adapter constructor and save it as a member.

3) Minimize repetitive work in onBindViewHolder implementation

For example, in the following code:

```
viewHolder.cartoneValue.setVisibility(position % 2 == 1 ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
```

//Controllo da togliere in futuro
You are calculating the same logic twice. Better to calculate it once and reuse the outcome:

```
int cartoneVisibility = position % 2 == 1 ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE;
viewHolder.cartoneQuantity.setVisibility(cartoneVisibility); //Controllo da togliere in futuro
viewHolder.cartoneValue.setVisibility(cartoneVisibility); //Controllo da togliere in futuro
```

4)Spinner Adapter should also recycle the views

In CartSpinnerAdapter.getView() you are also allocating memory. It happens (every time * list item * count) - That is a lot of allocations. Please use the convertView instead. Have a look on this tutorial dzone.com/articles/android-listview-optimizations